# Odd backgrounds/borders behavior when using css transitions for height, positions, and transformations

Tags: css, hover, z-index, transparent, transition

I really *really* thought I was being clever...

I wanted an elegant way to have a button with a hover effect of the background doing a wipe of some kind (top to bottom, left to right) using a soft color transition. I figured the best way to do that would be to create a box using the `:after` pseudo-class and either mess with the height or the position of it on hover, keeping it behind the actual  element with `z-index`, and using `rgba()` notion for the `<a>` tag's transparent background.

I succeeding in making that: http://jsfiddle.net/MrPickle/ysdhexbq/3/

The thing is, every now and then while mousing through that menu, a thin line will be left across the bottom of the button. I can imagine that this problem lies solely with my own browser's rendering engine, but I'd like to know if any of y'all see it too, or if anyone might have an explanation for what would cause that behavior.

The example in that fiddle there uses `transition: top` as the method for hiding the box created by `:after`, but I had the same results when using `transition: height` and `transition: transform`.

Actually, scratch that, I had worse results. If you want to see the bug happen a *lot*, check this one http://jsfiddle.net/MrPickle/ysdhexbq/5/ it works better (read: worse) if you pass your cursor all the way through before the element has a chance to finish the first transition.

Comment: What browser are you using? its working just fine on GC and FF.

Comment: I'm using Google Chrome Version 39.0.2171.95 m on Windows 7

Comment: Like I said... it might just be me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a trick that might help: force hardware acceleration.

All you need to add is:

```
a:after {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

My update to your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TheIronDeveloper/ysdhexbq/9/

By adding `translate3d`, it flips the browser into a `~hardware accelerated mode`, that basically allows your css to perform significantly better.

Heres an article discussing about it for the `filter:blur` style (`filter:blue` is very taxing on the browser, which is why hardware acceleration is extremely useful)
http://blog.kaelig.fr/post/47025488367/css-filters-in-the-real-world

Comment: I'm not sure if that's the most elegant solution. I'm seeing a lot of jitter now on the first few times that the transition fires after each page load.

Are there any general benefits to having hardware acceleration enabled all the time?

Comment: It shouldn't be more jittery... heres a few articles that talks about it in more depth. http://davidwalsh.name/translate3d and http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/increase-your-sites-performance-with-hardware-accelerated-css

Comment: I updated the code, changing where I put the translate. I'm not noticing jittery behavior when I test, but that could just be my box is doing very well.

Comment: My GPU is kinda..well... let's just say I don't use top of the line stuff for my dev environments. 

If I apply -webkit-transform directly to the a:after section, though, it run's like oil on glass.

Comment: Awesome, well we both learned something then. I'm glad I was able to help :)

Comment: ack- I didn't notice your second comment. GMTA, though, am I right?

Answer (score 0):

Well.. The hardware acceleration that The Iron Developer suggested definitely stops the bug from occurring on my machine, but the first few times the transition fires it looks kind of jittery. Given that the transition I'm going for isn't really that taxing, I don't feel as though invoking more hardcore system power would be a waste of painting time.

I fiddled a bit, though, and I've noticed that when the parent `div` has a border around it, the area in which the line *would* show up is spoken for...I guess.

Here's my updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MrPickle/ysdhexbq/8/

Seems to run pretty fast and I'm not noticing the issue that I had before.

Comment: Can confirm, I don't see the issue either.